# How do I read all the data that should come with UART in STM32F4?

Tags: stm32, uart, usart

I am currently working on USART with STM32 and it was working while I'm using usart interrupt. It was filling the rxBuff while I am sending with HTERM via USB but it is not filling while I am trying in the main block. It just takes first character of the transmitted data. For example, I tried to send hello, it just takes "h" into rxBuff and stops. When I try to send it again, this time rxBuff becomes [h,h] which means it only takes the first character.

Working:

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) {
    
    rxBuff[i++] = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
    
    if (i > RX_BUFFERSIZE ){
        i = 0;
    }
    USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
}
```

Not working :

```
int main(void){

while(1){ 
    if ( USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET ){
        rxBuff[i] = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
        i++;
    }
    if (i > RX_BUFFERSIZE ){
        i = 0;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the library code, but I suspect that you're losing data due to not reading it from the UART's receive register quickly enough, you can check that by looking at bit 3, Overrun Error in the UART's Status Register.

Comment: Well, thanks. It was about how quick. I change some other codes to get fast enough data, it worked.